# C# SQL Server Reading quantities from database and displaying it in the message box

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

So i am almost finish for my POS using C# and sql server management studio, but i have a problem displaying the available quantity for the specific product , in my POS if you put a Quantity that is larger than the Stocks(the quantity of each product is based in my Stocks) and hit the add button there will be a message box that will prompt to the user that the only available quantity for this product is only like that.

This is for identifying if the quantity exceeds:

```
 public void Q_tity()
    {


        try
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            con.Open();
            string qwe = "Select MIN(Quantity/Quantifier) from Stocks where ItemID in (Select ItemID from Recipe where MenuID in (Select MenuID from Menu where ItemName ='" + txtProd.Text + "'))";


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qwe, con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (txtProd.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Input a correct format", "Format info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {


                    double val = double.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                    Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(val);



                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The ingredient on recipe cannot identify. please fix it from the maintenance form", "Recipe Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

[image: This is for identifying if the quantity exceeds.]

This is the add button that should prompt the user:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtQuant.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Quantity Field is Required!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            Q_tity();
            con.Open();

          //  con.Close();
            if (Quantity < Convert.ToDouble(txtQuant.Text))
            {
                string qwe = "Select MIN(Quantity/Quantifier) from Stocks where ItemID in (Select ItemID from Recipe where MenuID in (Select MenuID from Menu where ItemName ='" + txtProd.Text + "'))";


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qwe, con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                MessageBox.Show(txtQuant.Text + " is unavailable! \n The Available Quantity of  " + txtProd.Text + " is " + dr + " only!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                con.Close();
            }
```

[image: This is the add button that should prompt the user]

And sadly this is the result:

[image: And sadly this is the result.]

Comment: please don't use images, paste your code in the question.

Comment: Without seeing your code or anything- Could make a stored procedure return a datatable with all of the data necessary then use LINQ to get a count (quantity) of all items per column

Comment: i've just updated my question , i added the codes with the images, thank you!

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: use SQL parameters rather than string concatenation to create queries. `cn` is redundant and can be removed. Note that IDataReader has methods like `GetInt32` and `GetDouble` rather than the `ToString`/ `double.Parse`/ `ConvertToInt32` that you're doing.

Comment: Here are some reasons [why not to upload pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 1):

You must use ExecuteScalar() rather than ExecuteReader in your case

Here is fix

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtQuant.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Quantity Field is Required!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            Q_tity();
            con.Open();

            //  con.Close();
            if (Quantity < Convert.ToDouble(txtQuant.Text))
            {
                string qwe = "Select MIN(Quantity/Quantifier) from Stocks where ItemID in (Select ItemID from Recipe where MenuID in (Select MenuID from Menu where ItemName ='" + txtProd.Text + "'))";


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qwe, con);
                int qty = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //<--  use executescalar


                MessageBox.Show(txtQuant.Text + " is unavailable! \n The Available Quantity of  " + txtProd.Text + " is " + qty + " only!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```